# Add images in project in new Xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift

In new Xcode 9 I want to add images in project. But If I add images and try to use it in code or in storyboard my images not showing in simulator. But in Xcode 8 all works fine. How to fix it?

Comment: If you are not using Assets, check the target for those images. In Xcode9, this is a known issue.

Comment: @AshishKakkad I m not using images in assets

Answer (score 7):

**Note : This Problem does not Exist Anymore in newer XCode**

If you have dragged image in your project, you must select **Copy If Needed** While adding any file into your project.

[image]

After Adding Image take a look at your image if it is available to target, I have face similar  issue with other file types too.
In xcode9 it was not selected by default even after selecting copy if needed.

[image]

Comment: I've noticed that too, even though the target is selected in the modal, when I go in the inspector it isn't. I've seen many people complaining about it on Apple's forum... And I can actually reproduce this bug every time... don't Apple developer use Xcode?!

Comment: @nyg - Hope they fix this soon.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - this is **super** annoying. With XCode 9, now in addition to dragging a new image into the XCode Project Navigator (the left-hand list of files), you now have to go into **Targets** for your project, go to "**Build Phases**" and manually add the image file to "**Copy Bundle Resources**" using the "**+**" button at the bottom of the list of files.

This is required for any object you used to have to just drag into the project, including third-party frameworks and bundles.

PS: in dragging the image into your project you don't have to have "Copy Item if needed" selected if the image file is already somewhere in your project folder or a subfolder thereof.

Comment: "" manually add the image file to "Copy Bundle Resources" using the "+" button at the bottom of the list of files. "" worked for me.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have to handle multiple images, it is probably more convenient to copy the resources to your target app in the General Settings > Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources 
[Copy Bundle Resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MS6ru.jpg)

This does the same as checking Target Membership for the resource – but you can add multiple images to your target app at once.

Answer (score 0):

Check release notes of XCode 9.1:

**Adding files to a project now adds them to the selected targets. (34551617)**

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html