# UIImageView disappear for Xcode 9 and iOS11, working fine for below iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode9

[image]

One of my iOS project is working fine for iOS 10. But when I run same code on iOS 11 Simulator build with Xcode 9, all UIImageView's images of my projects is not showing on simulator and device too, Background image on Button and cells are showing but Normal UIImageView is disappearing from Controller. Even it's not showing Background Color on that Image View.

What I did to resolve above issue are mentioned below:

- Clean Build Uninstall App from simulator,
- Cleared Derived Data and Archives
- removed and added images again with copied target.
- Added images in Images.xcassets with all three sizes.
- Removed auto layout/Constrains and also added Auto layout/Constrains to check above scenario.
- Created a fresh View Controller and added images and also added background color on that, its showing in Storyboard but when I run the Code its dis appears from Simulator and also from device.

All above mentioned points or solution are not working in my case.

check this image for Debug View hierarchy: And I am assuring, images on that ImageViews are copied to target.

Comment: it is unlikely to guess/ reproduce the problem you are facing, try posting your code so people around can have look at it and try to figure something out

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Dev_Tandel but I haven't wrote a single line code for that, I just added a New Controller on Story board in My project and added a Image view on that ,when I run my code Image View is disappear from device and Simulator.

Comment: will you check for this answer once ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46462200/3548469 might help

Comment: Did you use Debug View Hierarchy ?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @Dev_Tandel I already checked copied target option. Target is selected for my images.

Comment: @RajeshkumarR check this image for Debug View hierarchy: And I am assuring, images on that ImageViews are copied to target. 

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdVhN.png

As u can see all UIImages are not Showing in this Image URL..Please provide some solution.

Comment: @RajeshkumarR While debugging using View Hierarchy , I found  that image has Alpha value 0, but I set this to 1 in Storyboard, can you explain or give solution why its set to 0 automatically?

Comment: @RajeshkumarR Thank you very much, while debugging using View Hierarchy, I found somewhere in my code this " [super setAlpha:alpha];" line is written for some conditions thats why all images alpha become 0.


Thanks a lot