# Can't find URL from files using Bundle main url

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle

I'm trying to play some small .wav files using AudioToolBox library, but I just can't get the url for the files that I dragged into the project folder (the folder which contains the classes, etc.)

```
if let soundUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: name, withExtension: "wav") {
    //make use of AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID...
}
else {
    print("sound wasn't found")
}
```

I tried all combinations of possible drags to xcode (Copy itens if needed, Create groups, Create folder references) and very frequently I Clean the project, but still I always get "sound wasn't found". I truly don't know what information to give, but my approach was working until some days ago, then it suddenly stopped...

PS: Not sure if it's a useful information but I printed the list of files at Bundle.main.bundlePath and I didn't find any of the files I wanted, although they all appear in the list of files in the left (that contains codes, xcassets, Main.storyboard, etc.)

Comment: have a look at this may this help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46462200/3548469

Answer (score 20, accepted):

- Click at one of your wav files
- At the right side, there will be a list of options
- The last option of this list is a tab called **Target Membership**
- Check if this wav file you chose marks your current project as target

hope that helps :)

Comment: I could not find the option above. But I was able to go to "build phases" => targets (the app) => copy bundle resources (I added the resource file right there). It started working after that (the file was read correctly).

Comment: @uudaddy can't find that option. I'm going `myProject.xcodeproj` > Targets: `myProject` > `Build Phases` > ??? (I have `Dependencies`, `Compile Sources`, `Link Binary With Libraries`, `Copy Files`). When I add my file to Copy Files, with `Copy only when Installing` checked, Path `usr/share/man/man1`, and `Absolute Path`) it does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Daniel's answer is right in this case. However this message can also occur because the code is in a framework bundle that is part of the project's workspace. In this case, `Bundle.main` will get you the main project bundle and you should instead use a different bundle constructor, such as `Bundle(identifier: <id>)` or `Bundle(for: type(of: <object>))` (where `object` is a class appearing in the bundle you want to load from).

Comment: any good resources on making custom bundles? never had to do this before but I believe this is exactly my problem (first custom framework im making)

Comment: Sorry, not off the top of my head. I came across the problem because a third-party library included its own bundle of resources.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is getting this error while using react native, make sure that you've added your model to xcode workspace (xcode -> project's left side menu -> add files to "Yout Prj" -> select your file). I had this error when I added my model in vs code and xcode didnt know where to find.